# How to get grunt.file.readJSON() to wait until file is generated by another task

Tags: gruntjs

I'm working on setting up series of grunt tasks that work with RequireJS r.js compiler:
1) generates a .json file listing of all files in a directory
2) strips the ".js" from the filename (requirejs requires this)
3) use grunt.file.readJSON() to parse that file and use as a configuration option in my requirejs compilation task.

Here is the relevant code from my gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
    // create automatic list of all js code modules for requirejs to build
    fileslist: {
        modules: {
            dest: 'content/js/auto-modules.json',
            includes: ['**/*.js', '!app.js', '!libs/*'],
            base: 'content/js',
            itemTemplate: '\t{' +
                '\n\t\t"name": "<%= File %>",' +
                '\n\t\t"exclude": ["main"]' +
                '\n\t}',
            itemSeparator: ',\n',
            listTemplate: '[' +
                '\n\t<%= items %>\n' +
                '\n]'
        }
    },
    // remove .js from filenames in module list
    replace: {
       nodotjs: {
           src: ['content/js/auto-modules.json'],
           overwrite: true,
           replacements: [
                { from: ".js", to: "" }
           ]
       } 
    },
    // do the requirejs bundling & minification
    requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                appDir: 'content/js',
                baseUrl: '.',
                mainConfigFile: 'content/js/app.js',
                dir: 'content/js-build',
                modules: grunt.file.readJSON('content/js/auto-modules.json'),
                paths: {
                    jquery: "empty:",
                    modernizr: "empty:"
                },
                generateSourceMaps: true,
                optimize: "uglify2",
                preserveLicenseComments: false,
                //findNestedDependencies: true,
                wrapShim: true
            }
        }
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-fileslist');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['fileslist','replace', 'requirejs']);
```

I'm running into a problem where, if the "content/js/auto-modules.json" file doesn't already exist on load of my config file, the file.readJSON() is executed immediately, before the file exists and the entire task fails and throws "Error: Unable to read file " If the file already exists, everything works beautifully.

How can I set this up so that the task configuration waits for that file to be created in the first task, and modified in the second task before it tries to load & parse the JSON in it for the third task? Or is there another way (perhaps using a different plugin) to generate a json object in one task, and then pass that object to another task?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Old post but I had a similar experience.

I was trying to load a some json config like:

```
conf: grunt.file.readJSON('conf.json'),
```

but if this file did not exist then it would fall in a heap and not do anything.

So I did the following to load it and populate defaults if it didnt exist:

```
    grunt.registerTask('checkConf', 'ensure conf.json is present', function(){
    var conf = {};

    try{
        conf = grunt.file.readJSON('./conf.json');    
    } catch (e){
        conf.foo = "";
        conf.bar = "";
        grunt.file.write("./conf.json", JSON.stringify(conf) );
    }

    grunt.config.set('conf', conf);

});
```

You still may have some timing issues but this approach may help someone with a readJSON error.